# close all the sockets after using it? on server side

Tags: java, sockets

Do I have to close all the sockets after using it? Where should I put them in this code? My program just works normally when I run it. However, when I re-run it, it said "Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind". Therefore, I think I did not close all the socket after using it.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Server2 {
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    int PORT = 5555;      // Open port 5555
    //open socket to listen
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(PORT);
    Socket client = null;
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Waiting for client...");
        // open client socket to accept connection
        client = server.accept();
        System.out.println(client.getInetAddress()+" contacted ");
        System.out.println("Creating thread to serve request");
        ServerStudentThread student = new ServerStudentThread(client);
        student.start();


    }

}
```

}

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question. Have you tried your own suggestion?

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos: But I dont know how to close sockets and where to put it. Where ever I put the socket.close(), it said wrong.

Comment: you need to a have shutdown hook  , whenever you receive process terminate signal then set the exitServer to true,this should be a volatile variable and happens in separate thread.Also look at the source code of Tomcat HttpServer, you might get an idea!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `server.close()` in a `finally` block.

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(PORT);
try {
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Waiting for client...");
        // open client socket to accept connection
        Socket client = server.accept();
        System.out.println(client.getInetAddress()+" contacted ");
        System.out.println("Creating thread to serve request");
        ServerStudentThread student = new ServerStudentThread(client);
        student.start();
    }
} finally {
    server.close();
}
```

Comment: Now in Java 7 you can try with resources;
`try(ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(PORT)) {...}`. It will release the resources properly at the end (will do null check etc..)

Answer (score 0):

`Address already in use: JVM_Bind` - means, that you operation system is not closed socket after previous use. It closes on timeout about 30-180 seconds.

I don't realy know how to do this in java, but in `C` code it may be done like this, before `bind` system function call:

```
int yes = 1;
setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int));
```

That mean: set the flag (option) `SO_REUSEADDR` to `sockfd` socket.

In java must exists appropriate mechanism for do the same.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are running an infinite while loop , have a boolean variable to say when to stop , i think you are not exiting gracefully, that is why port is not closed.

May be you can try like this

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Server2 {
static int NUM_CONN_TO_WAIT_FOR=15;
boolean exitServer =false;
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    int PORT = 5555;      // Open port 5555
    //open socket to listen
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(PORT);
    Socket client = null;
    static int connections =0;
try
{

    while (!exitServer ) {
        System.out.println("Waiting for client...");
        // open client socket to accept connection
        if ( connections < NUM_CONN_TO_WAIT_FOR )
        {
          client = server.accept();
          System.out.println(client.getInetAddress()+" contacted ");
          System.out.println("Creating thread to serve request");
          ServerStudentThread student = new ServerStudentThread(client);
          student.start();
        } else
        {
            exitServer =true;
        } 
        connections++;

    }
} catch (Exception e)
{
   System.out.println(e.printStackTrace());
}
finally
{

   if ( client != null)
        client.close();

   if ( server!= null)
        server.close();

}

}

}
```

Comment: thanks for figuring out my mistake. But what if I don't know NUM_CONN_TO_WAIT_FOR. Anyway, thanks!